# How get the return value of checkbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I am sorry because this look like a doubled post, but i saw a lot of other threads and i cant understand anything that i am doing.

I am trying to make an has_and_belongs_to_many but i am stuck.

I managed to make the form display the right information, but i dont know how to save it.

I got:

Orb class:

```
class Orb < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :descr, :id, :nome, :orb_type_id, :orbt

  validates_presence_of :nome, :orb_type_id
  validates :nome, :uniqueness => true

  belongs_to :orb_type

  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

Book class:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dataf, :datai, :descr, :id, :nome

  validates_presence_of :nome
  validates :nome, :uniqueness => true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :orbs

  # allows project page to add items via checkboxes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orbs

end
```

A _form:

```
 <% @book.each do |book| %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "orb[book_ids][]", book.id, @orb.books.include?(book), id: dom_id(book) %>
      <%= book.nome %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

And the controller:

```
def new
  @book = Book.all
  @orb = Orb.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @orb }
  end
end
# GET /orbs/1/edit
def edit
  @orb = Orb.find(params[:id])
  @book = Book.all
end
# POST /orbs
# POST /orbs.json
def create
  @orb = Orb.new(params[:orb])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @orb.save
      format.html { redirect_to @orb, notice: 'save was successful' }
      format.json { render json: @orb, status: :created, location: @orb }
    else
      format.html { render action: "Novo" }
      format.json { render json: @orb.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
# PUT /orbs/1
# PUT /orbs/1.json
def update
  params[:orb][:book_ids] ||= []
  @orb = Orb.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @orb.update_attributes(params[:orb])
      format.html { redirect_to @orb, notice: 'save was successful' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "Editar" }
      format.json { render json: @orb.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

With this, the form has a checkbox with the right values, but it wont be save anywere.
I dont know what i am doing, can some one me explain what i have to do?

Comment: Why i cant find a full exemple of this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join table to use has_and_belongs_to_many

```
class CreateTableBooksOrbs < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :books_orbs, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :orb,  :null => false
      t.references :book, :null => false
    end
    add_index :books_orbs, [:book_id, :orb_id], :unique => true
  end
end
```

see here my working version : https://github.com/senayar/books

Comment: Hey, i tried to change the migration as you said (i already have created it). I made also some more things, like set the accepts_nested_attributes_for. The form get the tags (the book list) and show the checkbook properly, but it doesn't save anything in the joint table!

Comment: in the matter of fact, if i use :orb :book i got an erro:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16:in `block in trace_on': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)